# dask set_index gives different index type compared to that from_pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am trying to read a csv using dask and then resample it based on its timestamp index.

The csv file has content like:

```
Time,data
2015-01-01,0
2015-01-02,1
2015-01-03,2
2015-01-04,3
...
```

Method 1: Using `dask` to load the data directly and then setup the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
data_sample = dd.read_csv('test_data.csv')
meta=pd.Series([], name='time',dtype=pd.Timestamp)
data_sample['Time'] = data_sample['Time'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, meta=meta)
data_sample2 = data_sample.set_index(data_sample['Time'])
data_sample2.index.head()
```

And I got:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04',
           '2015-01-05'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', freq=None)
```

However, when I am trying to do:
    data_sample2.resample('1M').mean()

I have the following error:
    TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Method 2:

If I use `pandas` load the data and then convert it to `dask.dataframe`, it seems to be OK:

```
pd_data = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')
pd_data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(pd_data['Time'])
pd_data.set_index(pd_data['Time'],inplace=True)
pd_data.index
data_sample_from_pd = dd.from_pandas(pd_data, npartitions=1)
data_sample_from_pd.index.head()
```

And the dtype seems to be the same:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04',
           '2015-01-05'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', freq=None)
```

And the resample works fine:

```
data_sample_from_pd.resample('1M').mean().head()

data
2015-01-31  15.0
2015-02-28  44.5
2015-03-31  74.0
2015-04-30  94.5
```

Any idea why those two methods gives different result in executing `resample`? Any suggestions that how I should do to get method 1 work? Thank you!